Calculate the distance between the lines $AC$ and $BD
The problem
Let the tetrahedron $ABCD$ be $BC=CD=8, AB=AD=10, AC=BD=12$. Calculate the length of the segment joining the means of the edges $AC$ and $BD$ and the distance between the lines $AC$ and $BD$.
the idea
the drawing

As you can see I let X and Y the midpoints of $AC,BD$
$BX=XD$ because they are both medians in the triangles $ABC, ADC$, which are congruent by SSS.
This makes triangle $BXD$ issoscels and because Y is the midpoint of BD we get that $XY \perp BD$
By the theorem of the median in the triangle ABC we get that $BX=\sqrt{46}$ and using the theorem of phyagora in triangle $BYX => XY=\sqrt{10}$
Im not sure if I solved this right, if my rationament is right...
For the second point all I could think of is that
$\frac{AC* BD *d(AC,BD) *sin \angle(AC,BD)}{6}=V(ABCD)$

That distance is the altitude $YH$ of triangle $CXY$.

@Intelligentipauca Oooo...this is because $YH \perp AC , YH\perp BD$, no? Also is my idea for the first part correct? Thank you!

Wait a moment, does distance mean perpendicular distance?

@Gwen Yes...i saw your answer...XY isnt perependicilar, is just a median...

@IONELABUCIU okay then, I renamed it. Now is it alright?

In triangle $ACY$,
$$CY^2=BC^2-BY^2=8^2-6^2\implies CY=2\sqrt 7$$
$$AY^2=AB^2-BY^2=10^2-6^2\implies AY=8$$
And $AC=12$.
Applying Heron's formula, we get $A=3\sqrt{31}$. Taking $h$= perpendicular distance from BD to AC
Now $$A=\frac{1}{2}×h×AC\implies h=\frac{\sqrt{31}}{2}$$
I think this is correct. I never studied tetrahedral geometry...

Yeah...i think it's correct. Note that the line which represents the distance between 2 lines is the line that is perpendicular on both lines. To exprime A as $\frac{h*AC}{2}$ you need to show that h is YH where $YH\perp AC$ and we can also easily demonstrate that $HY\perp BD$...Hope this helps understand a bit of tetrahedral geometry
